# How do I use spaces in my command to cd to a directory and its sub directories using aliases?

Tags: shell, alias, tcsh

Suppose I am interested in this directory: `/home/username/../../../../.....dummy1`

And `dummy1` has these subfolders:

```
sub_dummy1
sub_dummy2
```

that in turn can consist of various directories and so on.

Is there anyway I can write an alias in `~/.cshrc` to navigate to `dummy1` and various subfolders ?

For example:

```
$ dummy1 sub_dummy1
$ dummy1 sub_dummy1/sub_sub_dummy1/sub_sub_sub_dummy2
```

Takes me to `sub_dummy1` if I hit Enter, shows me contents of `sub_dummy1` if I hit tab.

Comment: Doesn't `tcsh` have tab-completion? So `cd dummy1/ {tab}`, etc.

Comment: It is a standard behaviour in `tcsh`. Try to write `cd dummy1/sub` and then hit `ctrl + d`. Please read the section **Completion and listing** of `man tcsh` to understand how it works in details.

Comment: @roima `tcsh` has had programmable completion since 1983. `bash` had it only in 2000 (in beta). ;-) I remember that, for me, it was a shock to discover that bash finally got it. Obviously default key bindings are different.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more clearer. I am not interested in cd'ing to a directory then pressing tab to find out subfolders and so on. I am talking about having an alias which points to your directory of interest, typing that command without cd'ing to the directory and then hitting tab to see if a subfolder exists. I have already checked out 'Completion and Listing' section of tcsh. Duh ! Maybe I need to include a gif of some sort to explain things more clearly.